# My Visual c++ managed Unit test Project not Reading a input file

Tags: c++

I am using VisualStudio 2015, working on c++ managed Unit Test Project, I am giving the input values through text file but It not talking the values from the file

My code here

```
    struct employee
     {
       char name[20];
       char department[25];
       double salary;
      }
  [TestMethod]
  void Employee_Test()
  {

VEMPLOYEE Expectedemployee; //This is class 

employee emp_Test;

infile.open("Output_Expected.txt",ios::in);

        if (!infile)

            exit(1);


        for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        {

            infile >> emp_Test.name >> emp_Test.department >> emp_Test.salary;

            Expectedemployee.push_back(emp_Test);

        }
        infile.close();
       }
```

but infile values are not reading in my test code,
Expectedemployee container shows empty,

and my input file is

```
    Robin  IT 25000
    Nikson IT 20000
    Bob    IT 20000
```

Comment: Does it hit the `exit(-1)` line? If so, you might need to check the file path. Are there spaces and new lines in the file? Are the member variables strings?

Comment: Thanks for quick response,

Comment: File Path is correct and also going next step after exit(1),
It entering loop also but, the structure cannot reading the file in managed test Project.

"I applied same code in the direct project(not testing I written a program) It working fine but the problem with my managed C++ Test project, It not reading the input text file".

Is there any need to apply special symbols or functions in my managed C++ Unit test project for reading input file ??

Comment: @Lavakusa: if VEMPLOYEE is a class, where is the definition? can you add that to your post? Isn't it a vector?

Comment: @Shadi : VEMPLOYEE is defined in my actual Project called Employee management system,
I included that header file in my Manged Test Project,
so i can access the VEMPLOYEE  class..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some minor fixes on your code above, I run the code on my machines with (win10/gcc) successfully. so, I would guess the problem is most likely related to your class `VEMPLOYEE` and might be specific to the `push_back()` member function.

I used `VEMPLOYEE` as a `vector` for test purposes, I would expect  that you implemented your `class` to work like a container, but I cannot see any size/type related info in the 'VEMPLOYEE Expectedemployee;' line.

So, at least your file routine is good. check your `class`.

Comment: you are using windows10 and gcc ??

Comment: @Lavakusa: Yes, gcc is another compiler other than Visual Studio C++. I have not used my VSC++ because it has some problems in the mean time. However, most likely, this is should have no effect.

Comment: I fixed my `VSC++` and tested the code with it and it worked. I also tried the code with using a simple class instead of the vector and it worked. as I said, I doubt your `VEMPLOYEE ` class.

Comment: Thanks for valuable suggestions,

but it is not the general program, It only executed in visual studio 2015 manged C++ Test Project,(Means only running on a visual studio Manged unit test Explorer)
If we use this is a normal program it working fine,
but when I using as a test project it not working.
but I surprised one thing, you are using GCC in windows 10
up to now I thoughted GCC  only for Linux, I don't know how you are using, If you don't mine please tell me how to install GCC in windows 10,
I am also using windows10 with visual studio2015,
Please provide any URL's.

Comment: Sure, that would be more helpful.

Comment: I don't know how to edit my question(above )
I am the new beginner of this stack overflow.

Comment: You should see small `edit` at the end of the question. Alternatively, you can put the code in GitHub and post the link in the comments. For gcc you can install it as part of the Code::Blocks IDE. here you are the [*a direct installation link*](http://sourceforge.net/projects/codeblocks/files/Binaries/16.01/Windows/codeblocks-16.01mingw-setup.exe) other download methods available [*here*](http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/26)